# How to center verticaly blocks in two bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment, centering

I have this html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h2>Some big header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 select">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>TMP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">some more text</div>
</div>
```

and I am getting this result:

[image]

There is margin property on tag `h1` so there are some blank space above `h1`. There are no such space above `select`, so this elements are not centered.

### "What you've tried?"

I've tried bad and monstrouse method. I know it can be used to center divs. But not in this case... I have added `line-height` and `height` properties to the select:

```
.select {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.form-control {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Yes, it worked, but it is not relative at all. What if on left column there will be `h2` text, not `h1`?

[jsFiddle example of "what you tried?"](http://jsfiddle.net/35ysj/17/)

Also, "what you've tried?" 2: I tried to use `form-horizontal` class. Look this:

[image]

And the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 form-horizontal">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h2 class="control-label">Some big header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 ">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>TMP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, text in the left column is right aligned (as form label, obvious). I don't want this.

[jsFiddle example of "what you tried?" 2](http://jsfiddle.net/35ysj/21/)

So the question is: how I can center both elements vertically? Highly prefer using bootstrap classes and approaches. Don't suggest methods, where you specifying height of div, margins or paddings: it is not relative **at all.**

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use vertical alignment, I think you need to override the floating used by bootstrap classes, and use `inline-block` for the columns. It's not exactly a bootstrap approach, but I think it works and is responsive. There is one disadvantage that can be a bit annoying, is that you need to make sure there is no space between the `div`s...

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 vcenter-col">
            <h2 class="control-label">Some big header</h2>
        </div><!-- comment required to prevent line break...
     --><div class="col-xs-4 vcenter-col">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>TMP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.vcenter-col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35ysj/22/)

Did I understand correctly your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS :

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

BootStrap does a lot off things in CSS, so be careful to correcty set your CSS selector to not override all BootStrap CSS.

But, does your HTML can't change ? Is seems to me that the H2 element should have been a LABEL.

Comment: Exactly. Your solution will override all headers.